# AlarmManager.setRepeating not working when background

Tags: android

I'm using this code in order to make repeating notifications.

```
   private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 33);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), TWENTY_FOUR_INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
    }

    private Notification getNotification(String content) {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Scheduled Notification");
        builder.setContentText(content);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        return builder.build();
    }
```

This is my WakeFullReciever

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

    }
}
```

What I'm going to achive, is receiving notificaiton everyday (lets say every minute now). I'm getting them onlly when my app is in foreground. When I'm in background - I get nothing. I got my notification as soon as I get back to foreground. How to make this work?